# How to split word into two word in bash (Unix)

Tags: string, bash, unix, cpu-word

I currently have:

```
${array[2]}   =  1000($s3);
```

but I want to split this word into two word:

1st is   '1000'

2nd is  '$s3

and other one is :

```
50000($s4)
```

1st: 50000

2nd: $s4

then store them as string

How do I do that?

Comment: Can you use Python, Perl, awk or sed or only Bash?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `read` with custom `IFS`:

```
s='1000($s3)'
IFS='()' read a b <<< "$s"

echo -e "a=<$a>\nb=<$b>"
a=<1000>
b=<$s3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it in bash is:

```
for I in '1000($s3)' '50000($s4)'
do
   a="${I%(*}"
   b="${I#*(}"
   echo "1st=${a}, 2nd=${b%)}"
done
```

The `a="${I%(}"` removes everything from and including `(` to the end of the variable. `b="${I#(}"` removes everything until and including the `(`. The `echo 2nd=${b%)}` removes the final `)`.